# How can add a attribute of excel to style tag by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code, but it can't add attributes `"mso-height-source"` to `style` tag:

```js
function test(){
    $("#tableid").find("tr").each(function (index, oRow) {       
        $(oRow).css('color', 'red');
        $(oRow).css('mso-height-source', 'userset');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
<tr  style="height: 39pt;">
<td>testttt</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onClick="test();return false;" value="add"/>
```

How can add a attribute of excel to style tag by jquery?

Comment: You've said "to style tag," but you've also said "attribute." Those don't go together. Please show the DOM structure you want as a result.

Comment: I want add to : <tr  style="mso-height-source:userset;height: 39pt;color:red;">

Comment: The problem with that is that `mso-height-source` is not a valid style name, so although it's *possible* to force it into the `style` attribute, any change you make to the style later through jQuery will remove it.

Comment: Can add by other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `mso-height-source` style, so you can't set that style on an element reliably. You've said it has meaning to Excel, so... You *can* force it into the `style` attribute by setting the `style` attribute directly using text, like this:

```
const $row = $(oRow);
$row.css("color", "red");
let styleText = $row.attr("style");
const text = "mso-height-source: userset;";
styleText = styleText ? styleText + text : text;
$row.attr("style", styleText);
```

```js
function test(){
    $("#tableid").find("tr").each(function (index, oRow) {       
        const $row = $(oRow);
        $row.css("color", "red");
        let styleText = $row.attr("style");
        const text = "mso-height-source: userset;";
        styleText = styleText ? styleText + text : text;
        $row.attr("style", styleText);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
<tr  style="height: 39pt;">
<td>testttt</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onClick="test();return false;" value="add"/>
```

**but**, any change you make to it afterward will remove the invalid style. For instance, if I move the `.css("color", "red")` to the end of that code above, the `mso-height-source` disappears:

```js
function test(){
    $("#tableid").find("tr").each(function (index, oRow) {       
        const $row = $(oRow);
        let styleText = $row.attr("style");
        const text = "mso-height-source: userset;";
        styleText = styleText ? styleText + text : text;
        $row.attr("style", styleText);
        $row.css("color", "red");
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
<tr  style="height: 39pt;">
<td>testttt</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onClick="test();return false;" value="add"/>
```

This isn't a jQuery thing. If you use the `style` object to make a change (which is what jQuery does), that will also remove the invalid text from the `style` attribute:

```js
function test(){
    $("#tableid").find("tr").each(function (index, oRow) {       
        let styleText = oRow.getAttribute("style");
        const text = "mso-height-source: userset;";
        styleText = styleText ? styleText + text : text;
        oRow.setAttribute("style", styleText);
        oRow.style.color = "red";
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
<tr  style="height: 39pt;">
<td>testttt</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onClick="test();return false;" value="add"/>
```

So you can do this, but you must be sure **never** to change that element's style afterward with jQuery's `css` or the DOM's `style` object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `mso-height-source` css style, so rather than set it as a css,
use jQuery's [attr()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp) method.

```js
function test(){
    $("#tableid").find("tr").each(function (index, oRow) {       
        $(oRow).css('color', 'red');
        $(oRow).attr('mso-height-source', 'userset');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
<tr  style="height: 39pt;">
<td>testttt</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onClick="test();return false;" value="add"/>
```

Comment: it not add to style tag.

Comment: rather than css(), use attr()

Comment: there is no `mso-height-source` style

Comment: thank you, because i want add [mso-height-source] to style, it will valid in excel, but if i add outside style, it not valid.